# Calling selector before Segue Unwind Done:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 Views: RootView and ModalView

Currently I'm using the storyboard segue `unwind done:` to resign ModalView.

I then call `- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue { }` in RootView to reload data and do some other cleanup.

However, I need to save some data from a variable number of UITextFields in ModalView. Thus, I need the selector `setListInformationWhenDone:` to be called before `- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue { }`

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: @rdelmar its in ModalView

Comment: How is the segue being triggered, and which controller is addListViewController, the root or the modal.